# How do I query for entities that are "nearby" with the GeoPt property in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, geocoding, gql

How should I create a GQL query that returns the nearest entities (from my current location) based on their GeoPt property?  Should I just created a 'distance' function that calculates for a set of entities with a reasonably close distance?

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

App Engine doesn't treat GeoPt properties specially - it has no built in spatial indexing. There are a number of third-party libraries that add support for spatial indexing, however. The best one (in my opinion) being [geomodel](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/).

Comment: Is there any plan of supporting spatial indexing in the future?

Comment: @Lipis We haven't announced anything on the roadmap.

Comment: Nothing public at least.. I was hoping if you can share something that the rest of the world doesn't know.. :) Hopefully we'll see it one day before the end of the world that is coming in 2012.. :P Keep up the good work..

Answer (score 4):

You could store the locations in App Engine in a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) structure.

Here's one description of how it would be done: [Geographic Queries on Google App Engine](http://labs.metacarta.com/blog/27.entry/geographic-queries-on-google-app-engine/)

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'm going to some kind of digger achievement, but here it is:

I was looking for a solution for this issue and came across this Google's oficial docs:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings#Java_Queries_on_geopoint_fields

I really think that Google should have made some more noise about this. I find it weird that they have a lesson on Python for doing the same thing but says nothing on how to do it for Java.

Answer (score 0):

geohash set very close points in different hashes so another or next layer should be preferred. you can make a radius, quadratic inside/outside shape test or even any mathematical shape and test whether the point is within our outside the shape.